# How to make a clock showing UK time but the whole application is working in India Time

Tags: javascript, php, timezone, system-clock

I have the following Code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h+":"+m+":"+s;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code was refrenced from w3schools. But this code takes time from our system. But I want a javascript or server side method in PHP in which I can show UK time at the top of my page. It is easy to do so If I change the timezone to UK time in my config file but I want India time everywhere except that clock at the top of the page.

Comment: Javascript runs on the client's own machine (the user's machine), not on your server.  So, whoever runs this will get the time on their own computer.

Comment: I mean I can avoid javascript, Is there any method to get two formats time from server?

Comment: Consider using the [free clock on your site tool from TimeAndDate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/clocks/free.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `getUTCDate` or `toUTCString`

```
var d = new Date(); // local date
var n = d.getUTCDate(); // utc date
```

to get full date string

```
var d = new Date(); 
var n = d.toUTCString();
```

Demo `-->`  http://jsfiddle.net/gPRBH/

Comment: But if I alert n it shows only the hours not the minutsand seconds

Comment: UTC only aligns with the UK during the winter.  You also need to account for daylight saving time (BST)

Answer (score 1):

Use `getUTCDate()` and the related getUTC...() methods to access a time based off UTC time, and then convert.